# How can i animate beams of light in blender?

Tags: animation

So i used the blender tutorial on youtube for creating and animating abstract waves. from blend master.

and although those were helpfull, it didn't show me how to animate them actually moving around, like what im trying to do.
[image: Mega evolution beams]

[image: Beams of light from a pokeball]

I assume maybe the partical system is used for this? but im not sure. is there a tutorial on how to do this? or does anyone know how?

I haven't done much so far to even make this, as i have no idea where to start. i did make a simple abstract wave, but thats about it. An im using blender render.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you want. To get a better answer please **[edit]** your question and add information on what you have done so far in your scene. Please post images of your current settings and specify what render engine  you are using

Comment: Is this any different from your earlier question?